# Group Acting on a Ring

Tags: group-theory

What would be the definition for a group action on a ring? I could not find one online. Would this be acceptable?

A group action of a group G on a ring R is a map from G x R to R defined by g(r)=g.r satisfying the following properties:

(1) g.(g'.r)=(g.g').r       for all g,g'ϵ G, r ϵ R

(2) 1.r=r                   for all r ϵ R

(3) g.(r+r')=g.r+g.r'       for all g ϵ G, r,r' ϵ R

(4) g.(r.r')=(g.r).(g.r')   for all g ϵ G, r,r' ϵ R

(5) g.1=1                   for all g ϵ G

How about when g acts on "0" in R? Should I also have (6) g.0=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of an action of $G$ on an object $R$ as a homomorphism from $G \to Aut (R)$.  So in this case, with each $g \in G$ we associate a ring automorphism $\phi_g$.

Properties 1 and 2 guarantee $g \to \phi_g$ is a group homomorphism and $\phi_g$ is bijective.  3, 4, and 5 (I think you mean $g \cdot 1 = 1$) guarantee $\phi_g$ is a ring homomorphism. 6 is redundant since it follows from the fact that $\phi_g$ is a ring homomorphism; [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism).

Comment: I was also thinking about this in trying to figure out what equals $\tau (\sigma(a)*\sigma^2(a))$ for two permutations acting on an element $a\in R$, R a ring. I wanted to write $\tau (\sigma (a))*\tau (\sigma^2(a))$, but I couldn't seem to work things out. So, would we need to make all (1-5) definitions above, shouldn't they just follow from $G$ being a group acting on a ring $R$?