# Ring/Group actions on the definition of $R$-modules and $R$-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1_R$.

I found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244273/group-acting-on-a-ring) post the definition of the action of a group acting on a ring. And then, the following questions came in my mind.

**Question 1.** *What is the formal and common definition of a ring acting on a group?* (Without use of equivalent definition of action with endomorphisms, as [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) does)

So, from this to conclude that ["A module is a ring action on an abelian group"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/100565/101005).

**Question 2.** Now, let's remind to ourselves the following definition.

> **Definition.** An abelian group $(A,+)$ is an associative **$R$-algebra** if:
>   (1) $(A,+,\cdot) $ is a ring (not necessarily commutative), (2) $(A,+)$ together with the scalar multiplication $*:R\times A \longrightarrow A,\ (r,a) \longmapsto r*a$ is a left $R-$module and (3) the operations $*$ and $\cdot$ are compatible, that is 
>   $$\forall a,b \in A, \forall r\in R: r*(a\cdot b)=(r*a)\cdot b=a\cdot (r*b).$$

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1879448/326865) answer, we have a good way to think about the last axiom, as a result of an action.

*Does the ring $R$ acts on the abelian group $(A,+)$ through the map (scalar multiplication) $R\times A \longrightarrow A,\ (r, a)\longmapsto r*a$  ? And if the answer is yes, why? In other words, what are precisely the properties which should are satisfied, in order to have this kind of action?*

I'm trying to connect $R$-algebras with Group Theory.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand your questions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your comment. What is the unclear point?

Comment: The slogan "a module is a ring action in an abelian group" is unhelpful. It should read "a module is a homomorphism from a ring to the endomorphism ring of an abelian group".

Comment: @RobArthan Ok, but these two, are equivalent. Why is this unhelpful?

Comment: "Ring action in an abelian group" doesn't tell me what "ring action" means. "Homomorphism from ring to endomorphism ring" tells me exactly what is meant in a straightforward and memorable way.

Comment: @RobArthan Okay. Note that I took it from the attached link.

Comment: OK. That should answer your Q1. Can you now answer your Q2 for yourself?

Comment: @Rob Again we should have the induced action from the ring homomorphism $\rho :R \longrightarrow \mathrm{End}(M)$? But now, I if we define the map. Couldn't we have to write down the axioms? I m sorry, I m trying to get rid of this mess in my mind.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking for. The bit about the "mirror action" in the question you link to is not relevant here (it's saying that because $R$ is commutative you don't need to worry about the distinction between left $R$-modules and right $R$-modules, but that's not relevant to your problem). Please try to phrase your Q2 more carefully.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for the reaction. I tried to improve my question. Please, have a look. I think now it's better.

Comment: I think you'e missed out the word "ring" from condition (1) in the definition. $A$ doesn't act on anything here. It's $R$ that acts on $A$ in a way that is compatible with both the addition and multiplication on the ring $A$.

Comment: Oh God, I m full of typos. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to think about the ring R acting on a group G is for there to be a formal multiplication $$R \times G \rightarrow G$$  $$(r, g) \mapsto r\cdot g$$,

that moves group elements around. This multiplication agrees with the group action in the sense that it's distributive.

In practice, the action is clear--matrices on vectors, multiplication of numbers, etc. In general, the ring action has to be told.